# Как решить проблему с добавлением nuget пакета в .net core в os x?

Tags: .net, sql-server, macos, ssl, openssl

Проект ASP.NET Core в os x подключается к базе MSSQL.

Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found.

Установил пакет

> System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl

Но после установки пакета выдается та же ошибка. Пакет c "nativ" System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl не могу найти, есть только пакет System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Были установлены нужный пакет System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.

Необходимо было отдельно установить openssl как описано в туториале: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos